# How to swap files between windows in VIM?

Tags: vim, editing

When I work with VIM, I always have multiple windows visible. Sometimes I would like to have an easy way, to swap those windows in places. Is there any Plugin, Macro, etc to make this more easy? BTW, I use MiniBufExplorer.

Comment: By "swapping those windows in places", do you mean "opening the buffer that is in window A in window B, and vice versa, without changing the position of the windows"?

Comment: Yes, this is exactly what I want.

Answer (score 339, accepted):

There are a few useful commands built in which give you a certain amount of control, but it's not comprehensive.  The main ones are:

- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>r</kbd> (i.e. hold <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, press <kbd>W</kbd>, release <kbd>CTRL</kbd>, press <kbd>r</kbd>) - which rotates the windows (The first window becomes the second one, the second one becomes the third one, etc.)
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>x</kbd> - swap the current window with the next one
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>H</kbd> - move this window to the far left
- <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>K</kbd> - move this window to the top

(and similarly for <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>J</kbd> and <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>-<kbd>W</kbd>, <kbd>Shift</kbd>-<kbd>L</kbd>).  See:

```
:help window-moving
```

for more information.

Comment: This should be the "best answer"--native functionality, not a custom Vimscript.

Comment: Not completely, no. There are lots of use cases that can't be done using the built in window management without destroying and recreating windows. The swap buffers script allows these use cases.

Comment: note that ctl-w also works. ctl-W will close windows in some terminal emulators.

Answer (score 10):

I wrote and have been using the following code snippet in my vimrc for
copy-pasting my Vim windows.

This defines for example the following shortcuts:

- `<c-w>y`: "Yanks the window", i.e. stores the number of the buffer in the
  current window in a global variable.
- `<c-w>pp`: "Puts the window in Place of the current window", i.e. it reads the
  buffer number stored previously and opens that buffer in the current window.
  It also stores the number of the buffer that used to be in the current
  window.

If by "swapping those windows in places", you mean "opening the buffer in
window A in window B, and vice versa, without changing the position of the
windows", you can use the following keyboard sequence to swap the windows:

1. Select window A (either with mouse or with keyboard commands)
2. Press `<c-w>y` (yanking the buffer number)
3. Select window B
4. Press `<c-w>pp` (pasting the buffer)
5. Select window A
6. Press `<c-w>pp` (pasting the buffer again)

It works only in Vim >= 7.0.

```
if version >= 700
function! HOpen(dir,what_to_open)

    let [type,name] = a:what_to_open

    if a:dir=='left' || a:dir=='right'
        vsplit
    elseif a:dir=='up' || a:dir=='down'
        split
    end

    if a:dir=='down' || a:dir=='right'
        exec "normal! \<c-w>\<c-w>"
    end

    if type=='buffer'
        exec 'buffer '.name
    else
        exec 'edit '.name
    end
endfunction

function! HYankWindow()
    let g:window = winnr()
    let g:buffer = bufnr('%')
    let g:bufhidden = &bufhidden
endfunction

function! HDeleteWindow()
    call HYankWindow()
    set bufhidden=hide
    close
endfunction

function! HPasteWindow(direction)
    let old_buffer = bufnr('%')
    call HOpen(a:direction,['buffer',g:buffer])
    let g:buffer = old_buffer
    let &bufhidden = g:bufhidden
endfunction

noremap <c-w>d :call HDeleteWindow()<cr>
noremap <c-w>y :call HYankWindow()<cr>
noremap <c-w>p<up> :call HPasteWindow('up')<cr>
noremap <c-w>p<down> :call HPasteWindow('down')<cr>
noremap <c-w>p<left> :call HPasteWindow('left')<cr>
noremap <c-w>p<right> :call HPasteWindow('right')<cr>
noremap <c-w>pk :call HPasteWindow('up')<cr>
noremap <c-w>pj :call HPasteWindow('down')<cr>
noremap <c-w>ph :call HPasteWindow('left')<cr>
noremap <c-w>pl :call HPasteWindow('right')<cr>
noremap <c-w>pp :call HPasteWindow('here')<cr>
noremap <c-w>P :call HPasteWindow('here')<cr>

endif
```

Answer (score 7):

In my opinion, http://vimcasts.org/episodes/working-with-windows/ has the perfect answer for this question. In brief:

- `ctrl-w w`    cycle between the open windows
- `ctrl-w h`    focus the window to the left
- `ctrl-w j`    focus the window to the down
- `ctrl-w k`    focus the window to the up
- `ctrl-w l`    focus the window to the right
- `ctrl-w r`    rotate all windows
- **`ctrl-w x`  exchange current window with its neighbour**
- `ctrl-w H`    move current window to far left
- `ctrl-w J`    move current window to bottom
- `ctrl-w K`    move current window to top
- `ctrl-w L`    move current window to far right

Comment: What is the reason for adding an answer which brings no new usefull information to the post? This was perfectly answered 6 years ago. Are you doing ad campaign for vimcasts?

Comment: @mdrozdziel I appreciate this answer 9 years after the OP. Most concise answer with only the info i wanted.

Answer (score 4):

I asked a [similar question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2586984/how-can-i-swap-positions-of-two-open-files-in-splits-in-vim) around the same time:  I wanted a way to swap windows specifically without altering an arbitrarily complicated layout. I ended up making a vim plugin out of one of the solutions that was suggested. It's called [WindowSwap.vim](https://github.com/wesQ3/vim-windowswap); install it with your preferred vim plugin manager and give it a whirl.

With WindowSwap.vim,  you'd simply

2. `<Leader>yw` to yank a window.
3. Move your cursor to another window.
4. `<Leader>pw` to paste that window, swapping it with the position of
   the first one.

The key combinations are of course configurable to your preferences.

Answer (score 1):

As `<c-w>r` or `<c-w>x` has a restriction that you can't rotate or exchange windows When vertical and horizontal window splits are mixed. And `<c-w>H` may make the window layout change beyond your expectation especially when you have many windows.

So you may do some work to satisfy your particular needs of window/buffer switching. Here is am example to switching the current window with the top left window(typically I make it vertically maximized):

```
function! SwitchMainWindow()
  let l:current_buf = winbufnr(0)
  exe "buffer" . winbufnr(1)
  1wincmd w
  exe "buffer" . l:current_buf
endfunction
nnoremap <c-w><c-e> :call SwitchMainWindow()<cr>
```